# How to resolve "The Azure Key Vault url is malformed" exception

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, web.xml

I have cloned the project - https://github.com/Microsoft/Partner-Center-Java-Samples/tree/master/secure-app-model/keyvault from GIT to my local Eclipse.

Added tomcat server and when I run the partnerconsent project, I get this exception

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter [AuthenticationFilter]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The Azure Key Vault url is malformed.
    at com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder.vaultUrl(SecretClientBuilder.java:177)
    at com.microsoft.store.samples.partnerconsent.security.KeyVaultProvider.getKeyVaultClient(KeyVaultProvider.java:68)
    at com.microsoft.store.samples.partnerconsent.security.KeyVaultProvider.<init>(KeyVaultProvider.java:33)
    at com.microsoft.store.samples.partnerconsent.security.AuthenticationFilter.init(AuthenticationFilter.java:236)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:272)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4613)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:265)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "spec" is null
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:708)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:569)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:516)
    at com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder.vaultUrl(SecretClientBuilder.java:175)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.length()" because "spec" is null
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:614)
    ... 39 more
```

I have added the keyvault_base_url value in web.xml and it is well-formed. So, not sure why the exception is still coming.

Comment: Is your key vault URL well-formed? It should be something like `https://some-name.vault.azure.net/`

Comment: Yes it is well formed and matches the format which you've specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the repository code. Created an issue for the GIThub repo owners to make the change.

The arrowed statement (in the image) should come above the below statement because getKeyVaultClient method is using the variable vaultBaseUrl.

client = getKeyVaultClient();

[image]